# Store data in local storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I need to store application data in localstorage

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {
            userName:'',
            loggedInStatus: true,
            authToken: '',
            role: ''
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        addWebToken: function(state, data){
            state.user.authToken = data.token;
            state.user.role = data.role;
        },
        removeWebToken: function(state){
            state.user.authToken = '';
            state.user.role = '';
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getToken:function (){
            return  store.state.user.authToken;

        }
    }

})
```

I am not using any front-end frameworks. I need vuex-persistentdata cdn link but unable to find it on google.

Comment: which application data do you want to storage on local?

Comment: The one I mentioned on the top. Vuex store. Currently it stores it as global variables, I want to store it on localStorage so that on refresh data is not lost.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://cdn.rawgit.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/9d79a3e0/dist/vuex-persistedstate.min.js [Vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

Answer (score 0):

@Roy J already provided the CDN link in the comments (https://cdn.rawgit.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/9d79a3e0/dist/vuex-persistedstate.min.js).

But besides that you also need to pass the `vuex-persistedstate` as a plugin to Vuex:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
});
```

Read their docs over at Github: [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)